# Error while shutdown cassandra cluster from c# datastax driver

Tags: c#, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax

[image]

I am using Datastax C# driver to connect to Cassandra node from my C# application. My code works fine and I am able to retrieve all data and process them. However, when I try to shutdown the cluster after fetching records, its giving me the above error. Below is my code for the Connect method.

```
public ISession Connect()
{
    cluster = Cluster.Builder().AddContactPoint(NodeIp).Build();       //node ip
    ISession session = cluster.Connect(ClusterName);                   //database name
    return session;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This bug is fixed on the latest version

Comment: has it been fixed just now after posting this question?

Comment: Yes, I created a ticket and included it for the release that was coming :)  https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/CSHARP-247 . You should update via Nuget and it will be fixed without the need of a workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When shutting down the cluster, the driver uses `WaitHandle.WaitAll()` that is not supported in STAThreads.

The driver should support STAThreads when shutting down, I created a [ticket for it](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/CSHARP-247).

In the meantime, as a workaround, you can start a new task and wait for it.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => cluster.Shutdown()).Wait();
```

---

**Update**

This bug is fixed on the latest version.

Comment: Thanks, the above query worked, it is not giving me error now. But can you let me know when will my cluster shutdown? how will I come to know that it has shut down?

Comment: Shutting down is a blocking operation in the C# driver, so it will be shutdown when the line executed (the workaround includes a Wait())